24.04 - How to find "what" is changing DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf
Question: How can I remove whatever is setting this DNS server, incorrectly?  The methods
I see for manually changing a DNS server in Ubuntu 24.04 don't seem to in place here as I don't seem to have the files that they are referring to.
Issue: Server is using the wrong DNS server, its set somewhere and I can find where it is. I'd rather have it use the router's default DNS (which will point to an internal IP).  This is for a Docker home lab.
Currently, the DNS is set (somehow) to 192.168.0.112. That was an older server, now defunct. To note, this server is running the DNS Docker container.
This is validated with:
root@myserver:/etc/systemd# resolvectl status
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: uplink

Link 2 (enp8s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.112 1.0.0.1

Link 3 (wlp7s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.112 1.0.0.1
[...]

My current DNS server is running off of 192.168.0.110 which is what my router is set to use as well as the default DNS. My Windows machine gets that in the DHCP request.
/etc/resolv.conf
[...]
nameserver 192.168.0.112
nameserver 1.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.0.112
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 1.0.0.1
search .

I looked at networkctl --status
● Interfaces: 1, 4, 12, 18, 24, 10, 28, 30, 20, 16, 8, 6, 14, 26, 66, 64, 68, 7>
       State: routable
Online state: online
     Address: 192.168.0.110 on enp8s0
              192.168.0.108 on wlp7s0
[...]
     Gateway: 192.168.0.1 on enp8s0
              192.168.0.1 on wlp7s0
         DNS: 192.168.0.112
              1.0.0.1

Other posts that I have read said that /etc/resolv.conf will get fed from: /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail , that file does not exist.
root@myserver:/etc# cd r
rc0.d/        rc3.d/        rc6.d/        rmt           rsyslog.d/
rc1.d/        rc4.d/        rcS.d/        rpc
rc2.d/        rc5.d/        resolv.conf   rsyslog.conf

Some said netplan would be the way, but the only file I have is 50-cloud-init.yaml:
root@myserver:/etc/netplan# ls
50-cloud-init.yaml

network:
    ethernets:
        enp8s0:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlp7s0:
            access-points:
                <<SSID>>:
                    password: <<password>
            dhcp4: true

/etc/systemd/network/ is empty.
Only other files/systems I can think of show are:
/etc/systemd/networkd.conf (Essentially empty, all commented out, kept headers)
[Network]
[...]

[DHCPv4]
[...]

[DHCPv6]
[...]

and /etc/systemd/resolved.conf Also essentially empty, except turned off DNSStubListener to run DNS server in Docker
[Resolve]
[...]
DNSStubListener=no
[...]


Background Information:
root@myserver:/etc/systemd# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:        24.04
Codename:       noble

root@myserver:/etc/systemd# apt-get update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
llHit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done

Did some semi pointed grep searches:
user@myserver:~$ grep -Ril 192.168.0.112 /run 2>/dev/null
/run/systemd/netif/links/3
/run/systemd/netif/links/2
/run/systemd/netif/leases/3
/run/systemd/netif/leases/2
/run/systemd/netif/state
/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
user@myserver:~$ grep -Ril 192.168.0.112 /etc 2>/dev/null
/etc/resolv.conf



You've indicated that your server is using the wrong DNS address but it used to be correct and set to 192.168.0.112. You also indicate it has since changed to 192.168.0.110. Therefore, with your server configured to acquire its IP address via DHCP, as defined in your Neplan config file, I think you simply need to renew your DHCP lease.
This can be done with the following command, which will renew the lease for both of your interfaces:
sudo networkctl renew enp8s0 wlp7s0
You may need to force this with:
sudo networkctl forcerenew enp8s0 wlp7s0
Next, I see that you issued the command, grep -Ril 192.168.0.112 /run 2>/dev/null, which resulted in several files. This indicates that this nameserver has been stored in these files. If you inspect the contents of /run/systemd/netif/leases/2 or /run/systemd/netif/leases/3, you'll see your DNS servers listed.
Additionally, if you run resolvectl status, you'll see the same DNS servers listed for each respective link.
After renewing your leases, your lease files should be updated and the output of resolvectl status should reflect these changes.

Default config
Now with that said, you've modified your server away from the default configuration, and I'm not sure if this was intentional or if it happened during the course of your troubleshooting. So let's get it back to normal.
/etc/systemd/resolved.conf
You've modified /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to disable the stub resolver. I suggest that you re-enable it by simply commenting out the line, DNSStubListener=no. The default config of this file should be as follows. Notice all directives are commented out.
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
#  terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
#  Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
#  any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults. Local configuration
# should be created by either modifying this file (or a copy of it placed in
# /etc/ if the original file is shipped in /usr/), or by creating "drop-ins" in
# the /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/ directory. The latter is generally
# recommended. Defaults can be restored by simply deleting the main
# configuration file and all drop-ins located in /etc/.
#
# Use 'systemd-analyze cat-config systemd/resolved.conf' to display the full config.
#
# See resolved.conf(5) for details.

[Resolve]
# Some examples of DNS servers which may be used for DNS= and FallbackDNS=:
# Cloudflare: 1.1.1.1#cloudflare-dns.com 1.0.0.1#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1111#cloudflare-dns.com 2606:4700:4700::1001#cloudflare-dns.com
# Google:     8.8.8.8#dns.google 8.8.4.4#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8888#dns.google 2001:4860:4860::8844#dns.google
# Quad9:      9.9.9.9#dns.quad9.net 149.112.112.112#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::fe#dns.quad9.net 2620:fe::9#dns.quad9.net
#DNS=
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#DNSSEC=no
#DNSOverTLS=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#LLMNR=no
#Cache=no-negative
#CacheFromLocalhost=no
#DNSStubListener=yes
#DNSStubListenerExtra=
#ReadEtcHosts=yes
#ResolveUnicastSingleLabel=no
#StaleRetentionSec=0

But let's back up and explain what happens when you set DNSStubListener=no in this config file. Basically, this disables the local caching stub resolver and sets the contents of /etc/resolv.conf to your uplink nameservers. But it doesn't do this by writing directly to /etc/resolv.conf. Instead, it creates a symlink from /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf. As a result, with /etc/resolv.conf by default being a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf, this config effectively changes the contents of /etc/resolv.conf. Let me outline this...
In the default configuration of Ubuntu 24.04 server:

/etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf is a static file
The contents of /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf has 127.0.0.53 as the nameserver, which is the local caching stub resolver:

    $ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 23 09:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

    $ ls -l /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf 
    -rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-resolve systemd-resolve 920 Aug 28 00:37 /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

    $ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    # This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
    # Do not edit.
    #
    # This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
    # /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
    # internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
    # configured search domains.
    #
    # Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
    # currently in use.
    #
    # Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
    # through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
    # different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
    
    nameserver 127.0.0.53
    options edns0 trust-ad
    search .

After changing the config directive to DNSStubListener=no in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, notice the changes.

/etc/resolv.conf is still a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf is no longer a static file defining the local caching stub resolver.
Instead, it's a symlink pointing to /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, which lists your local uplink servers.

    $ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 23 09:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

    $ ls -l /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf 
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 systemd-resolve systemd-resolve 11 Aug 28 00:40 /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf -> resolv.conf
    
    $ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
    # This is /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
    # Do not edit.
    #
    # This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
    # /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
    #
    # This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients directly to
    # all known uplink DNS servers. This file lists all configured search domains.
    #
    # Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
    # through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
    # different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
    #
    # See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
    # operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
    
    nameserver 8.8.8.8
    nameserver 1.1.1.1
    search .

Remember: After making any changes to /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, you need to reboot the computer or restart systemd-resolved with the command: sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.
/etc/resolv.conf
As outlined above, /etc/resolv.conf should be a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf. So you've either deleted this symlink and created a static file, or the change is a result of setting the config directive, DNSStubListener=no, in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf. Therefore, if it's not a symlink to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf, delete your file and create a new symlink as follows:
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf

The link should look like the following:
$ ls -l /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39 Apr 23 09:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Afterwards, look at the contents of /etc/resolv.conf. If you have #DNSStubListener=no commented out (or set to DNSStubListener=yes) in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, you should see the following:
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search localdomain

As an aside: If you want to see the stub resolver in action to query the uplink servers, I wrote an answer on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange that walks you through it.

More Info
Netplan
For some basic information regarding Netplan, Ubuntu server is configured via Netplan .yaml configuration files located in /etc/netplan/. As you've noticed, you have a file called: /ect/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml. This file was created during installation of your server and you can configure this as needed. Currently, it's configured to acquire an IP address via DHCP. This also acquires DNS servers and the gateway address.
An example of defining a static IP address:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses:
        - 10.10.10.2/24

To override the DNS servers offered via DHCP and set your own:
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp4-overrides:
              use-dns: no
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8]

After making any changes, run sudo netplan try and sudo netplan apply.
After applying your changes, files are created in /run/systemd/network.
For example, with your Netplan config setup as DHCP, a file similar to the following is created:
$ sudo cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s3.network 
[Match]
Name=enp0s3

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
    

For more info: Netplan documentation
For some history of Netplan: A declarative approach to Linux networking with Netplan
/etc/systemd/network/
You indicated that /etc/systemd/network/ is empty. This is normal. This directory is for manual configuration of your network devices via systemd.network. See man systemd.network and man systemd.networkd.

Thanks so much for this. My default config was corrupted upon upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS yet I did not know anything about it until I read your answer. After fixing symlinks to resolv.conf, not only is my internet speed faster, but I was also finally able to configure adguard home successfully alongside surfshark vpn. Regardless, anyone who upgraded to 24.04 LTS, should at least check their default config, since the symlink from stub-resolv.conf to resolv.conf is surely missing.

I've faced same issue as you.
I didn't find what is changing original /etc/resolv.conf (aka /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf) file(s) so I've changed /etc/systemd/resolved.conf to add DNS servers from our company as primary and fallback I've put Google ones, like:
[Resolve]
DNS=10.200.32.11 10.200.32.12 10.200.165.11
FallbackDNS=8.8.8.8

Actually, if I run VPN server, it gives me nameservers from our internal network, and after disconnection it should used Google one ;-)

/etc/resolv.conf is managed by systemd-dnsmasq. Read man systemd-dnsmasq and use it, rather than directly editing /etc/resolv.conf

I appreciate the guidance here.  I don't have systemd-dnsmasq installed right now, but def will look into it.  Though I am perplexed what actually is setting the DNS server right now to *.112, as NetworkService / netplan and resloved  don't seem to be the ones changing the set DNS servers.
My "fear" is that I install dnsmasq and there is still something else overriding it.

AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a conversation site. If you have new information on your original question, [edit] the question and add it. If you have a new question, [ask] it. Do not try to start conversations in a Comment. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

@waltinator This isn’t entirely true. First of all, there is no manpage for systemd-dnsmasq. Second, dnsmasq is a consumer of /etc/resolv.conf,  not a producer. Finally, dnsmasq is not installed by default in Ubuntu 24.04 Server.

@NomObscura, you don’t need to install dnsmasq. I’ll find some time later to write up an answer to try and help you.
